# PHP 5.3 Use and Symfony Forms

Tags: php, autoload, symfony

Im trying to include some Symfony form components into my project.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
```

If I do this I get :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form' not found
```

Even though I know that this is where the Form elements are. Using

`require 'Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php'`

works  ,but I need to alias the form elements to get the class to work.

EDIT:
Trying this after copying the ClassLoader to the project still brings same error:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony' => __DIR__.'/Symfony',
));
$loader->register();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set up autoloading. The 'use' does not do that for you. To do this, include the UniversalClassLoader, tell it where to load the Symfony files from and register it.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony' => __DIR__.'/vendor',
));
$loader->register();
```

The 'use' statement just aliases the fully-qualified class name to a shorter version for you to use in that file.

Comment: Thanks. I am attempting to use the Form class separate from the framework.  I still get the same error even when copying the 'ClassLoader' dir to my project.

Comment: It's probably easiest to also copy the Form component to your project. So basically just add those two components into vendor/Symfony/Component/<Component>.

Comment: Ive already done this and it still says that they cannot be found.

Comment: That's because it should be `'Symfony' => __DIR__`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/UniversalClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

set_include_path(__DIR__.PATH_SEPARATOR.get_include_path());
$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->useIncludePath(true);
$loader->register();
```

That should work for you, yes?